# Index.js imports .tsx file after build specifically on windows

Tags: reactjs, windows, typescript, react-native, rollupjs

I'm trying to build a module I want to modify and use in my project. I cloned the module, installed the dependencies and built it but when I tried to run it I kept getting an error `Error: Unable to resulve module './Calendar.tsx' from 'build\index.js'`. I then looked at `index.js` in the build folder and it seems to be be requiring a `tsx` file which seems wrong.

The module does compile correctly on linux and osx which is even more confusing.

The github issue has both the correct `index.js` and the version I got:
https://github.com/acro5piano/react-native-big-calendar/issues/264

I have 0 expirience using rollup so I don't have any idea what to try next. Is there some windows specific thing I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

try to add ts - the tsx is the convention fot ts file in react - look for ts loader

Comment: The `rollup.config.js` uses `rollup-plugin-typescript2` to process ts